# Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories' from assembly 'System.Data'

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, .net-4.5

First of all some context: my project exists out of a common project that contains all the DAL stuff and a web project. Now the common project is written in .NET framework 4.5 while the web project is written in .NET Core 2.0.

When trying to acces the repositories of the DAL project I get following error:

> Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories' from assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Now I'm not sure what to do now. I have added the System.Data.Common nuGet package to my web project, but without succes. How can I slove this problem preferably without altering the common DAL project? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DbProviderFactories` won't be available until .NET Core 2.1 ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/25410)). Either wait for that, or start porting your DAL to .NET Standard 2.0 (which is a good idea anyway) and see if it really needs this class in all scenarios.

Comment: @JeroenMostert well porting the DAL project to .NET standard 2.0 is a huge task so I think waiting for .NET Core 2.1. In the meantime I maybe could use the preview version of .NET Core 2.1.